# Wicket text input disappears after setEnable on TextArea

Tags: java, ajax, apache, wicket

I have a TextArea, and a associated CheckBox to disable and enable the TextArea (setEnabled(Boolean)), which is used to decide if it is a required field or not.

My problem is that Wicket does not keep the text in the TextArea when it is disabled (setEnabled(false)). It clears the input.

How do I keep the value in the TextArea before setEnabled is called on it? I need to update the Model serverside,
Can I do a AJAX request to update it? I haven't found any example.

```
checkBox.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

       if (textField.isEnabled()) {
            textField.inputChanged();
            // Update text input in PropertyModel….
        }

        textField.setEnabled(false); // This change in state does not include text that have been typed in
        tekstFelt.setRequired(false);

        target.add(textField);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add an `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` for the `blur` event to the `TextArea` so that when you type in the textarea and leave the textarea (lose focus = blur) what you typed will be persisted by the model. Sample code:

```
private TextArea textarea() {
    TextArea textarea = new TextArea("textarea", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "value")){

        @Override
        protected void onConfigure() {
            setEnabled(condition());
        }

    };
    textarea.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    textarea.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("blur") {

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        }
    });
    return textarea;
}
```

I also recommend that wheter the textarea is enabled or not you should set in `onConfigure()` of the textarea. When you want to updated the textarea you just add it to the `AjaxRequestTarget` and the textarea knows if it should be enabled. This is a best practice and is not directly correlated to your question.

Comment: wow! What a great answer :) Works like a charm. I had no idea of the "blur" event. Is there a full list somewhere of all the event/behaviour types?

Comment: Sounds very similar to the JavaScript event names. Looks like they are identically named.